# How do I create links at the top of WP_List_table?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-list-table

I am trying to create links like the ones in the post tab (see image below).

[image]

I created my `WP_List_table` but I am not sure how to create those links or how to get them to show a different db query.

I know about the `extra_tablenav` function in the class but this adds things after the bulk action area, so this doesn't seem to do what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a quicklink to the Posts Admin Published|Scheduled|Trash menu](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19418/how-to-add-a-quicklink-to-the-posts-admin-publishedscheduledtrash-menu)

Comment: Please see my solution to your question in [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19418/how-to-add-a-quicklink-to-the-posts-admin-publishedscheduledtrash-menu/52075#52075). Close voting this a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Ignore that - this is a custom instance of `WP_List_Table`. Will post solution below.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in the comments, if this is an existing table you wish to add/remove links from, [see this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19418/how-to-add-a-quicklink-to-the-posts-admin-publishedscheduledtrash-menu/52075#52075).

If this a custom subclass of `WP_List_Table`, e.g.:

```
class Wpse56883_WP_List_Table extends WP_List_Table{

 //Class methods here

}
```

Then you add these links by overriding the `get_views()` method. This should return an array: `array ( id => link )`. This should link back to the page, attaching some value to a query variable (which I'll call `customvar`).

When constructing the links, check for  the current value for `customvar` and conditionally add the class `current` to highlight in bold the current view.

So (inside) your class.

```
function get_views(){
   $views = array();
   $current = ( !empty($_REQUEST['customvar']) ? $_REQUEST['customvar'] : 'all');

   //All link
   $class = ($current == 'all' ? ' class="current"' :'');
   $all_url = remove_query_arg('customvar');
   $views['all'] = "<a href='{$all_url }' {$class} >All</a>";

   //Foo link
   $foo_url = add_query_arg('customvar','foo');
   $class = ($current == 'foo' ? ' class="current"' :'');
   $views['foo'] = "<a href='{$foo_url}' {$class} >Foo</a>";

   //Bar link
   $bar_url = add_query_arg('customvar','bar');
   $class = ($current == 'bar' ? ' class="current"' :'');
   $views['bar'] = "<a href='{$bar_url}' {$class} >Bar</a>";

   return $views;
}
```

Then in your `prepare_items` method you can retrieve the `customvar` method and alter your query according to it's value.

```
 function prepare_items(){
     //Retrieve $customvar for use in query to get items.
     $customvar = ( isset($_REQUEST['customvar']) ? $_REQUEST['customvar'] : 'all');
 }
```

**Note:** The links can be used to perform actions. I would store the 'action' value in the query variable `action` (remember to use nonces!). Then hook onto `load-{$hook}` ([see Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-%28page%29)), check permissions and nonces, and then perform the action.

If you are going to include 'action links', make sure you use nonces - and you should only display the link for users with the necessary capabilities.

Comment: Hi, I am creating a custom class that extends WP_List_Table. And I am trying to use the get_views() method to add links on top of my table. But it is never called. Is there anything else that have to be done so that method links appears?

Comment: Yes! You have to call it manually. Your code will look like: $table = new Table(); $table->prepare_items(); $table->views(); $table->display();

Answer (score 7):

You have to call `views();` when rendering the page content.

Put `<?php $wp_list_table->views(); ?>`
after page title and before the form.

> See: \wp-admin\edit.php to see when is called.

Comment: Thanks! That was missing for me.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem i have created a custom style , you can follow

```
//Add a filter hook first 

add_filter('views_edit-your_custom_post_name',array($this,'prefix_post_status_links'));

 function prefix_post_status_links($views) {
         ?>
        <div class="gwf-tab-header">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <?php
                $views = array(
                 'all' => '
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active p-0" href="edit.php?post_type=your_custom_post_name">
                        <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
                        All Entries
                    </a>
                </li>',
                'active' => '<li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link p-0 text-success" href="edit.php?post_status=active&post_type=your_custom_post_name">
                        <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
                        Active
                    </a>
                </li>',
                'inactive' => '<li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link p-0 text-warning" href="edit.php?post_status=inactive&post_type=your_custom_post_name">
                        <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
                        Inactive
                    </a>
                </li>',
                'trash' => '<li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link p-0 text-danger" href="edit.php?post_status=trash&post_type=your_custom_post_name">
                        <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
                        Trash
                    </a>
                </li>'
                );
                 return $views;
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
```